# Using tools to create a new namespace

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy, clang-ast-matchers

I have a large codebase filled with names such as `MyCompanyMyDeptMyType`. This is making the code rather hard to read. I would like to use a tool to move all these names to a nested namespace `MyCompany::MyDept`.

My header files would look like

```
namespace MyCompany {
namespace MyDept {   
  // here goes the code with shorter names
}
}
```

and my cpp files would end up with `using namespace MyCompany::MyDept;` at the top.

Does such a tool exist? ([clang-rename](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-rename.html)?) If not, is my best shot to write my own [clang AST visitor](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html)?

Comment: You could probably write a small C++ program with less than 10 lines to parse a header file and output the modified header file.

Comment: Unless your command has organised its departments in the same way one organises types in a namespace, the `MyDept` layer should not be necessary.

Comment: @Peter really? I would be impressed if you could write a parser that succinctly. Also, you are assuming no templates.

Comment: @M.A Not sure I understand your first comment. `MyDept` corresponds to my part of the organization. If I don't have it, some types might clash with types from other departments in my company.

Comment: @Touloudou why are types in your codebase bound to departments? Do your integer types vary between departments?

Comment: @M.A Sadly, there is rather little communication between departments. My `FooManager` could well clash with the `FooManager` from another part of the company.

Comment: @Touloudou :) surely you want to make one generic `FooManager` for all departments? and not have everyone write their own. But I feel your pain, seen it happen before.

Comment: @M.A If I could write everything from scratch, sure. :) Right now, given the current state of affairs, I am trying to at least get readable code.

Comment: Are the types you mention inside a superior namespace?

Comment: @user1810087 No they are not. However, these will not be used outside of my department if this is where you are going.

Comment: If you want to this on files basis and you have an editor that supports regex replacing (i know VS studio does - i suspect VS code does as well, as well as a host of other code editors) - it should be possible to build a regex that does this i would say - then you may or may not need to autoformat afterwards.

Comment: @darune Doing this on a per-file basis is going to be tricky, because everything is so intertwined. If I change one base class for example, all derived classes must change too, etc. If I change a header file, many many files will break down the line.

Comment: @Touloudou I see, then you can use VS studio or resharper. If you can load your entire codebase that needs changing into VS studio then you should be able to change on a class basis.